# While loop not showing first item when use "oci_fetch" to check the array is non empty in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, oracle, while-loop

I am trying to hide empty table content by checking the array is empty or not

```
if (oci_fetch($stid_non) > 0){
```

but in while loop it not showing first item when I using the if condition to check non-empty array.
below is my code...

```
oci_execute($stid_non);

    if (oci_fetch($stid_non) > 0){

        print "<table class=\"table table-bordered table-striped\" id=\"myTable\">";
        print "<tr class=\"header\"><td>Entry User ID</td><td>User Name</td><td>Entry Date</td></tr>";

        while($ST_ARRAY_NON = oci_fetch_array($stid_non)) 
        {
            print "<tr>";
                print "<td>$ST_ARRAY_NON[0]</td>";          
                print "<td>$ST_ARRAY_NON[1]</td>";          
                print "<td>$ST_ARRAY_NON[4]</td>";
            print "</tr>";
        }       
        print "</table>";
    }
    else {
        print "Empty Value in Array";
    }

oci_close($conn);
```

It displaying the result without showing the first item. That means if the result should 10 row, but it showing 9 row by removing the first item.

- BTW, If I remove the "*if (oci_fetch($stid_non) > 0){*" it showing the actual result.

Can anyone please help me to fix the issue. Thanks for advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, the line

```
if (oci_fetch($stid_non) > 0){
```

is retrieving the first row and so this row isn't read in the main loop.  As this is used to only display the headings if there is some data, I've rearranged the code so that there is a flag to indicate if the headings have been displayed.  This is set to true after the first row shows the headings.

Also after the loop, if the header flag is still false, no rows have been displayed...

```
oci_execute($stid_non);

$headerDisplayed = false;    
while($ST_ARRAY_NON = oci_fetch_array($stid_non))
{
    if ( $headerDisplayed === false )
    {
        print "<table class=\"table table-bordered table-striped\" id=\"myTable\">";
        print "<tr class=\"header\"><td>Entry User ID</td><td>User Name</td><td>Entry Date</td></tr>";
        $headerDisplayed = true;
    }
    print "<tr>";
    print "<td>$ST_ARRAY_NON[0]</td>";
    print "<td>$ST_ARRAY_NON[1]</td>";
    print "<td>$ST_ARRAY_NON[4]</td>";
    print "</tr>";
}

if ( $headerDisplayed )
{
    print "</table>";
}
else {
    print "Empty Value in Array";
}
```

I would also remove the line

```
oci_close($conn);
```

Comment: Wow.. charming. It working like a magic. 
Thanks for your help. BTW, I used `$headerDisplayed == false` instead of  `$headerDisplayed === false` which showing the same result. Is there any reason to use === instead == ?

Comment: `===` is sometimes better to get into the habit of when testing for true and false.  More that some functions can return 0 for a valid answer (array positions), but false when something hasn't worked. == will not recognise the difference whereas === will.